# Open website and edeting the html with python

Tags: python, urllib2

am a little stuck. The program is supposed to open a website and read save it in a file. Then it is supposd to read everything up til it finds a string and delete everything before it and save it again in a new file. But when i run it i get the first file with the html in and the second file i am trying to make turns out to be blank. Anyone that can point me in the right direction?

```
import fileinput
import re
import requests
import sys

#linkToGet=sys.argv[1]                  //Hvordan hente link fra terminalen
#r = requests.get(linkToGet)

#nameOfFile=sys.argv[2]

#Hent nettsiden og lagre kildekoden som en textfil
r = requests.get('https://www.bibel.no/Nettbibelen?query=ud8MMrJeKwHNJdqN05oJoRgo89+A24MHmKzQYWJRSygk2+FVqgPK3UvcYb+xB3j7')  #Bare sånn jeg kan builde enkelt fra Atom
print (r.text)
f= open("kap3.txt","w+")
f.write(r.text)
f.close

#Fjern all tekst frem til en linje

TAG = """<A HREF="/Nettbibelen?query=ud8MMrJeKwHNJdqN05oJoc7CfBH5MjZKa4lw+sXwPrCzmbEZmCUXfQz2ApCFmHAq" class='versechapter'>50</A> """

tag_found = False
with open('kap3.txt') as in_file:
    with open('kap3ren.txt', 'w') as out_file:
        for line in in_file:
            if not tag_found:
                if line.strip() == TAG:
                    tag_found = True
            else:
                out_file.write(line)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are only calling `out_file.write(line)` if you HAVE found the line you are looking for, your else satement should be indented to be for the inner if.

```
for line in in_file:
    if not tag_found:
        if line.strip() == TAG:
            tag_found = True
        else:
            out_file.write(line)
```

Of course this makes the outer if basically useless so it can be simplified to this:

```
for line in in_file:
    if line.strip() == TAG:
        # you're done here so you can break the loop
        break
    else:
        out_file.write(line)
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for pointing that out! But still when i have a string i know is in the file it will not edit it properly

Comment: Could you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: If i want to remove everything up until the line "<A HREF="/Nettbibelen?query=ud8MMrJeKwHNJdqN05oJoc7CfBH5MjZKDfTQjiVLrvFFR8diL0Z3dC961e43rFXw" class='versechapter'>50</A> " it will not remove anything. If you try to run the code and set that as the TAG it will just output the whole file

Comment: The website edits links everytime you get it. Thanks for the help! :)